# Template Type deduction of std::pair change in behavior? (no, explicit keyword error)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++11, std-pair

I am using Visual Studio versions 2005 and 2012 for this, the code below compiles and there are no issues in vs2005, but it generates an error in vs2012. I have distilled the code I was working on down to the sample below which compiles and runs (in vs2005)

```
#include <map> 

//Arbitrary class
class SimpleClass
{
private:
     int member;

public:
     explicit SimpleClass( int i ) : member(i) {}
     operator int() const { return member;} 
};

//In code I have a map with these types and make_pair is invoked
//when an insert occurs into that map
typedef std::pair<SimpleClass,SimpleClass> SCPair;

//simple fn to replace myMap.insert(...)
void lvalref_test( const SCPair& sp )
{
    return;
}

int main( unsigned int argc, const char** argv ) 
{
     const int anInt = 2;
     //make_pair creates a pair<SimpleClass,SimpleClass> from
     //the instance of pair<int,SimpleClass> in the normal way
     //and Because SimpleClass is constructable from an int, 
     //the creation succeeds (In vs2005)
     lvalref_test( std::make_pair( anInt, SimpleClass(1) ) );
     return 0;
}
```

vs2012 gives me:

> error C2664: 'lvalref_test' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const SCPair &'

I've looked at the difference between the std::pair implementations in both

**vs2005**

```
template<class _Other1,
    class _Other2>
    pair(const pair<_Other1, _Other2>& _Right)
    : first(_Right.first), second(_Right.second)
    {   // construct from compatible pair
    }
```

**vs2012**

```
template<class _Other1,
    class _Other2>
    pair(const pair<_Other1, _Other2>& _Right,
        typename enable_if<is_convertible<const _Other1&, _Ty1>::value
            && is_convertible<const _Other2&, _Ty2>::value,
            void>::type ** = 0)
    : first(_Right.first), second(_Right.second)
    {   // construct from compatible pair
    }
```

I guess that the `enable_if` is causing the behaviour change, but I am not quite sure why.

I know how to fix the error I see, I can pass through an instance of SimpleClass and all is fine and dandy. *My Question here* is should this still deduce the correct template parameters and create the right pair type? Has this behaviour changed or have I made a mistake somewhere?

The answer is yes I made a mistake - I ignored the obvious `explicit` keyword throughout and dived headlong into the mechanism....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not compile. Your constructor requires an explicit construction, but by trying to implicitly convert the pair, you are trying to perform an implicit conversion. Strictly, this should not ever have compiled.

VS2005's behaviour is deficient- whether that's because of a Standard defect or because they were defective. The behaviour in VS2012 is correct.

Comment: Well I taught myself a lot in the process even if I ignored the simpler stuff....